# What can be done with inactive, unanswered questions from 1-rep users?

Tags: discussion

I have regularly seen inactive questions like [OpenVPN fails to start automatically](https://askubuntu.com/q/18988/6969), asked by new users. There are no answers, neither does the author reply.

What should be done with that kind of questions? Shouldn't those be deleted, it does not add anything helpful to Askubuntu.

Comment: Looks like that person was just around, maybe they just need an @username poke to remind them?

Comment: Won't they get notified if the comment is on their question?

Comment: Yeah but the last comment on there is from Dec 29th.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We already remove the following automatically with no intervention required:

- remove zero score questions with no answers, low views, <=1 comments that are more than 365 days old
- remove negatively voted questions with no answers more than 30 days old

Comment: So we have to wait till 27th December 2011 before they question dies? Can't it be lifted to 180 days (6 months)? I do not think it would make a difference.

Comment: I concur with @Lekensteyn.