# What can a low rep user do with an old forgotten duplicate post?

Tags: discussion

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798242/turn-on-proprietary-nvidia-graphics-driver-on-ubuntu-16-04-in-recovery-mode) is a duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) but has not been marked as so.

I could:

1. Answer the question & it should get marked.
2. Down vote the question & it will be [deleted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1067/what-can-be-done-with-inactive-unanswered-questions-from-1-rep-users) it time.
3. Comment to the user to delete the question.
4. Flag it for moderator attention.

I don't want to down vote it just because it's a duplicate question.

What should I do?  Should I just leave it alone? I would like advice for future questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct action to take is to flag it.  Click flag and then select "*it is a duplicate*".  Then you can enter the URL of the other post.

> [image]

Comment: thanks, i will do